# Obtaining current URL - when the URL includes a query string with multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, urlencode

I've noticed that whatever method I use for obtaining the current requests URL, the query string ampersands are always encoded.

```
Request.RawUrl
Request.Url
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Will always produce encoded results (notice the `&amp;`):

```
/Controller/View?arg1=weffe&amp;arg2=wefwe&amp;arg3=wefewge
http://domain/Controller/View?arg1=weffe&amp;arg2=wefwe&amp;arg3=wefewge
http://domain/Controller/View?arg1=weffe&amp;arg2=wefwe&amp;arg3=wefewge
```

How do I ensure the returned URL is not encoded in this fashion, and appears as such:

```
/Controller/View?arg1=weffe&arg2=wefwe&arg3=wefewge
http://domain/Controller/View?arg1=weffe&arg2=wefwe&arg3=wefewge
```

Any help much appreciated - I'm sure I've missed something obvious here!

Comment: Are you using the url in the view? or in the controller?

Comment: Are you sure that your incoming Url is actually `arg1=www&arg2=eee`? Check out what browser actually  navigates/requests.

Comment: @ChadRuppert - I am using the Url in the View.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Yes, the incoming url is definitely as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the URL actually encoded, or are you outputting it to the browser, and the output in the browser is encoded? If this is the case you can fix by using @Html.Raw(url) to bypass MVC's auto HTML encoding.

Comment: This is why i asked my question. Good call.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something simple, but for some reason I couldn't find out what was needed! SO Saves the day again...!

Answer (score 2):

Print your url without encoding it with:

```
@Html.Raw(Request.Url)
```